# how to access relations of laravel factory from inside another factory

Tags: php, laravel, model, relationship, factory

I have a model called `Company`, and `Field`s are added to it via an observer after it is created:

```php
    protected static function booted(): void
    {
        static::created(function (Company $company) {
            $company->fields()->createMany([
                ['name' => 'First Name', 'type' => \App\Enums\FieldType::TEXT],
                ['name' => 'Last Name', 'type' => \App\Enums\FieldType::TEXT],
                ['name' => 'Email Address', 'type' => \App\Enums\FieldType::EMAIL],
                ['name' => 'Phone Number', 'type' => \App\Enums\FieldType::PHONE],
            ]);
        });
    }
```

All of my relations are defined correctly.

I am trying to grab this relationship inside of another factory, called `Lead`.

Here is my setup:

seeder:

```php
        \App\Models\Company::factory(10)
            ->hasLeads(10)
            ->hasUsers(10)
            ->create();
```

Here is my `Lead` factory definition:

```php
    public function definition(): array
    {
        $company = Company::factory();

        return [
            'company_id' => $company,
            'fields' => [
                $company->fields->firstWhere('name', 'First Name')->id => fake()->firstName(),
                $company->fields->firstWhere('name', 'Last Name')->id => fake()->lastName(),
                $company->fields->firstWhere('name', 'Email Address')->id => fake()->safeEmail(),
                $company->fields->firstWhere('name', 'Phone Number')->id => fake()->phoneNumber(),
            ],
        ];
    }
```

this produces the following error:

> Undefined property: Database\Factories\CompanyFactory::$fields

how can i get the `fields` relationship from the `Company` factory inside of my `Lead` factory? I would like this to work with the observer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i figured it out:

```php
    public function definition(): array
    {
        return [
            'company_id' => Company::factory(),
            'fields' => function (array $attributes) {
                $company = Company::find($attributes['company_id']);

                return [
                    $company->fields->firstWhere('name', 'First Name')->id => fake()->firstName(),
                    $company->fields->firstWhere('name', 'Last Name')->id => fake()->lastName(),
                    $company->fields->firstWhere('name', 'Email Address')->id => fake()->safeEmail(),
                    $company->fields->firstWhere('name', 'Phone Number')->id => fake()->phoneNumber(),
                ];
            },
        ];
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).